# How to replicate the MainActivity.class in NativeScript for android

Tags: android, nativescript

I am creating local notifications but they have a custom probe. Unfortunately the local notification plugin cannot add a custom sound for android. I am using the android apis from nativescript to be able to launch the notifications which work fine. But pressing the notification does not return me to the app. Or I don't know if there is any way to do this from nativescritp

Answer (score 1):

Get the packageName and from the packageManager get: getLaunchIntentForPackage from the packageName. `let context=Application.android.context; let packageName=context.getPackageName(); let pg=context.getPackageManager(); let intent=pg.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);`